# Square Point of Sale API - Error code "amount_too_small", but card is charged?

Tags: square-connect

i'm making calls to the square pos ios web api with charges of $1.00 for system integration testing.

the calls are successful, in that they switch control to the square app, the card gets charged $1.00, transactions show up in the dashboard, i can refund them, etc. so obviously i'm sending the minimum amount suggested in the documentation to test the api (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-ios) due to the lack of a point of sale api sandbox?

why does the response return a status of "error" with an error_code of "amount_too_small" when it was processed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using an amount of at least `100` to represent $1 (or 100 cents). You should only get this error if you try to charge an amount lower than `100`.

My guess is that you are seeing transactions that you made previously, or you are getting replayed responses by reusing idempotency keys. If you are in fact getting an error in response while a transaction is being created, it seems like there is something wrong with our system. Could you record a video of what you are doing, or some detailed logs of requests & responses with headers?